# Sharepoint mobile view issues

Tags: 2013, javascript, mobile

I am working on Mobile View for SP 2013 site and I used some java script for better user experience, this java script works perfectly with IOS and ANDROID devices, when it comes windows phone like Nokia Lumia i have trouble with it.

I found issues like when do any click function page goes to top automatically.

I really appreciate, if anyone could help.

Comment: Without code it is virtually impossible to help you :)

Comment: The solution is to disallow support for poorly implemented technology. You wouldn't let someone browse your site with IE6, so why let them access it using a windows phone?